# In Python, i want to print concentric square for that i have written a code but i am not getting desired output

Tags: python, python-3.x

## input n taken here

```
n=int(input())

answer=[[1]]

for i in range(2, n+1):

    t=[i]*((2*i)-3)
    answer.insert(0, t)
    answer.append(t)
    for a in answer:
    a.insert(0,i)
    a.append(i)

answerfinal=[]

for a in answer:

    answerfinal.append("".join(str(a)))

for a in answerfinal:
    
    print(a)
```

Output:

```
4
[4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]

[4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4]

[4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]

[4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4]

[4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]

[4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4]

[4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

Desired output:

```
4444444

4333334

4322234

4321234

4322234

4333334

4444444
```

Comment: Note that `"".join(str(a)) == str(a)`. Do you mean to join the elements of the list itself, i.e. `''.join(a)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution to your problem with the right algorithm and output:

```py
n = int(input())

answer = []
k = 0
for i in range(n):
    temp = [(n-k) for _ in range(2*n - 1)]
    side = [x for x in range(n, n-k, -1)]
    answer.append(side + temp[k:len(temp) - k] + side[::-1])
    k += 1

k = 2
for i in range(n-1):
    answer.append(answer[n-k])
    k += 1

for a in answer:
    print(''.join(map(str, a)), end='\n\n')
```

Comment: Can you please tell me where I am wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Your logic doesn't seem to be right, and there is some bad indentation in your code as well.

To print the output properly instead of a list you can do:

```
for a in answerfinal:
    for i in a:
        print(i, end='')
    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the commas and spaces with nothing and then exclude the brackets:

```
for a in answerfinal:
    print(a.replace(', ', '')[1:-1])
```

Full code below:

```
n=int(input())

answer=[[1]]

for i in range(2, n+1):
    t=[i]*((2*i)-3)
    answer.insert(0, t)
    answer.append(t)
    for a in answer:
        a.insert(0,i)
        a.append(i)
answerfinal=[]

for a in answer:
    answerfinal.append("".join(str(a)))

for a in answerfinal:
    print(a.replace(', ', '')[1:-1])
```

Comment: as per your code square is not formed. I want output as:
4444444
4333334
4322234
4321234
4322234
4333334
4444444

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
for i in range(2*n-1):
    print()
    for j in range(len(answerfinal[i])):
        print(answerfinal[i][j], end='')
```

instead of

```
for a in answerfinal:
    print(a)
```

might help.