# I have written the code given below for concentric square in python. But i am not getting desired output

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
n=int(input())


answer=[[1]]
for i in range(2, n+1):
    t=[i]*((2*i)-3)
    t1=[i]*((2*i)-3)
    answer.insert(0, t)
    answer.append(t1)
    for a in answer:
        a.insert(0,I)
        a.append(i)

answerfinal=[]
for a in answer:
    answerfinal.append("".join(str(a)))
for a in answerfinal:
    print(''.join(map(str, a)), end='\n')
```

> I want the below output:

4444444

4333334

4322234

4321234

4322234

4333334

4444444

But I am getting the below output:

[4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]

[4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4]

[4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4]

[4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4]

[4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4]

[4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4]

[4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]

Can anyone tell me what mistake I am doing in my code?

Comment: Didn't you [ask this already with another account](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61028139/354577)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Python, i want to print concentric square for that i have written a code but i am not getting desired output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61028139/in-python-i-want-to-print-concentric-square-for-that-i-have-written-a-code-but)

Comment: Yes, but i have made some changes to my code but still getting output as string

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the join method from the second for statement:

```py
n=int(input())


answer=[[1]]
for i in range(2, n+1):
    t=[i]*((2*i)-3)
    t1=[i]*((2*i)-3)
    answer.insert(0, t)
    answer.append(t1)
    for a in answer:
        a.insert(0, i)
        a.append(i)

answerfinal=[]
for a in answer:
    answerfinal.append(a)
for a in answerfinal:
    print(''.join(map(str, a)), end='\n')
```